# Cant serve static files in NextJs + Storybook

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, storybook

The nextjs docs (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) state to add image file paths under the `public` directory.

I have a component that renders an image component and the file renders correctly on my nextjs project but doesn't render inside of storybook. The image file is currently living in `public/images/`

```
const renderImage = () => {
    const portraitClassName = cx({
        [styles.imageContainerPortrait]: true,
    });

    return (
        <img
            className={portraitClassName}
            data-testid="image"
            src="/images/portrait.png"
            alt={image.imgAlt}
        />
    );
};
```

This is my current config file for storybook

```
webpackFinal: async (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {
                        implementation: require("sass"),
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                    options: {
                        ident: "postcss",
                        plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer],
                    },
                }
            ],
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
        });
        return config;
    }
```

Is there something missing that would allow me to render images in the same manner as how Nextjs is set up?

Comment: Could you tell me the reason that your images are not rendered in storybook? I guess you meet 404 errors, try setting assetPrefix (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix) when running inside Storybook

Answer (score 14):

You need to tell storybook where to find your images.
In `nextjs` they stays in `public/` so you can just add `-s ./public` to your script to run storybook:

```
//package.json
{
"scripts": {
    "start-storybook": "start-storybook -s ./public"
  }
}
```

Here docs link for reference: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets#serving-static-files-via-storybook

Comment: What about if the path is in your css or scss?

Comment: `-s` is deprecated, inside of the main.js use `staticDirs: ['../public', '../static'],` instead.
That still dosen't work with css but there is a workaround, you could do an inline style css variable like `style={{"--myVar": "url('/test.png')"} as React.CSSProperties}` and use this inside of your css

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was I needed to tell **storybook.js** where my public resources were located, using **staticDirs**.

i.e: root > **.storybook** directory > `main.ts`

```
const config: StorybookConfig = {
 //other stuff .... 
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag',
  },

  staticDirs: ['../public/'], //<--- FIX    };

};
export default config;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify the .storybook/preview.js file like this:

```
import * as NextImage from 'next/image';

const OriginalNextImage = NextImage.default;

Object.defineProperty(NextImage, 'default', {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => (
    <OriginalNextImage
      {...props}
      unoptimized
      blurDataURL="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCAADAAQDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAFQABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAf/xAAbEAADAAMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMABAURUf/EABUBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMF/8QAFxEAAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECEf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8Anz9voy1dCI2mectSE5ioFCqia+KCwJ8HzGMZPqJb1oPEf//Z"
    />
  ),
});
```